# Flutter Unresolved class 'ApplicationName'

Tags: android, flutter

I wanted to upload my application to git, it gives a warning and when I say show the warning, I get an error like this. I just opened the android folder and synced, but I could not get a result. This issue only occurs when trying to upload my project to git. I tried many ways but failed
How can I fix this problem?

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.apmatik"
    tools:ignore="MissingVersion">
   <application
        android:label="apmatik"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1:

Setting `manifestPlaceholders` manually in our `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
⋮
defaultConfig {
   ⋮
    // Add This line
    manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
   }
   ⋮
 }
```

Solution 2 :
Add this code in `app/build.gradle` :

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
    }

    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
    }
    build{
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answers but not work! My gradle plugin version:7.2.1 gradle version: 7.4.2 and android studio: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Opened my AndoridManifest file and all these errors popped up.

Comment: It worked for me and it happened after adding oauth params in ManifestPlaceholders

Answer (score 3):

If your app does compile, then it is not your problem but rather an Android Studio linter issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are setting up a new Flutter project using Android Studio.
The default `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` files always show analysis errors for me, but the app launches fine.

Android studio runs several checks for you to help you catch errors before committing your code.  Those can be configured or disabled, but your question is really about why you can't commit to Git.  Actually, you can go ahead and commit the files anyway if you're just trying to get the project uploaded to git by clicking either of the buttons that shows up:

[image: Android Studio commit buttons]

Notice that the "Commit" and "Commit and Push..." buttons become "Commit Anyway" and "Commit Anyway and Push..."

You can click the link in blue to view the errors, but if you make any changes to any file, the buttons will reset to "Commit" which will run the checks again.

**`Commit Anyway and Push...`** will upload your commit to your upstream Git repo (Like GitHub if that's how you have it configured)